# Emacs Making ~files

Tags: backup, emacs

I was wondering if there is a way to make emacs stop making backups of files with the ~ at the end. (herpderp.html~) I am currently using windows xp 32 bit with emacs 23. Does anyone know how to make this stop?

Comment: ~ usually means temp file. Why do you want this to change?

Comment: well if i have a folder with some script files their are a ton of extra files that dont go away afterwards, is there a way to hide them? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the variable `backup-inhibited`. Setting it to non-nil means "no backups".

Answer (score 2):

To save the backup files in a different place you can customize `backup-directory-alist`.   It consists of a list of pairs.  The first in the pair is a regex to match the file name, and the second is the directory to save them in.  If nothing matches then the backup files are saved in the same directory as the original.  Below will save all backup files to `~/.emacs.d/backups` where they are out of the way until you need them.

```
(setq backup-directory-alist '(("." . "~/.emacs.d/backups")))
```

Comment: i did this for a while then one day realized that my emacs.d file was huge!